# Compose key with FCITX

Tags: input-method, compose-key, fcitx

I'm using Arch+KDE Plasma. In the Plasma settings, I added the Compose-key to right-control. Didn't change any other settings.

I recently installed FCITX (with the French AZERTY and the Japanese MOZC keyboards). Since then, my right-control key doesn't do anything anymore. I would like right-control to be the compose key with FCITX.

Their issue tracker says it has been [solved in 2014](https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx/issues/147), however it doesn't explain how to actually do it. Since the repo is archived, I don't know what's the correct place to ask them directly.